# Convertir lista de números a lista de objetos en typescript

Tags: typescript, arraylist

Estoy empezando con typescript y estoy batallando para convertir una lista de numeros a lista de objetos.

Al imprimir en consola mi lista la tengo así:

```
funciones: [4,23,33]
```

y necesito darle el siguiente formato:

```
funciones: [{id: 4}, {id: 23}, {id: 33}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes declarar una interfaz, que un array nuevo implemente esa interfaz y luego usar un `Map()` y lo que te devuelve para construir la nueva lista:

```
interface numberObj{ // declaramos interfaz
  id : Number // el elemento que la implemente tendra una propiedad 'id' de tipo number
}

let lista : Number[] = [12,14,34,56] // lista original
let listaObjs : numberObj[]; // interfaz implementada como array
listaObjs = lista.map((elem) => { return { id : elem }}) 
// map devolvera una lista nueva, que creara los objetos nuevos en cada posicion 

console.log(listaObjs)
```

Justamente la gracia de TS es lo estricto de los tipos, pero si queres cambiar el tipo de un dato es ponerle el tipo `Any`:

```
let lista : any[] = [12,14,34,56] // lista original ahora con el typo Any
lista = lista.map((elem) => { return { id : elem }}) 

console.log(lista)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay dos variantes de lo que necesitas, la primera forma es mediante tipos automáticos, esto es no requieres una definición explícita de tipos para que typescript detecte la conversión de tipos.

Si tienes definidio un arreglo de números tipo:

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
//    ^? ->  number[]
```

Con la función de map automáticamente se genera el tipo de dato deseado gracias a que se infiere del tipo de retorno de la función. Dicha función se vería así:

```
const result = numbers.map(n => ({ id: n }));
//    ^? ->  { id: number }[]
```

Puedes verlo funcionando acá:
[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBGCuBbARgUwE4RgXhgbQEYAaGAJhIGYSAWEgVgF0BuAKBdElnVQngBtYuBCgwQAdIgCGABwAUYHAD4YsgN4wAlgBMAXHBgBfAJRHWAejMwrMAHoB%20IA)

---

Si por alguna razón deseas ser explícito en el tipo de dato de retorno, o quieres definir tipos específicos para usarlos luego lo que puedes hacer es definirlos explícitamente así:

- Mediante un **type**

```
type WithId = { id: number };
```

- Mediante una **interfaz**

```
interface WithNumber {
  id: number;
}
```

El código final se vería así:

```
type WithId = { id: number };

const numbers: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; // (No es necesario el number[] ya que ts lo infiere automaticamente, pero somos explicitos)
const result: WithId[] = numbers.map(n => ({ id: n }));
```